# Upgrade from VMWare player to workstation

Tags: windows, vmware-workstation

I am a regular used of VMWare Player. I've got Windows XP and linux installed on it. Now I want to install Windows 8. It is not compatible with VMWare player, anyhow.

So I googled for solutions. I got one that I should install it on VMWare workstation. But during installation it asks for uninstalling VMWare player first. And I can't do that as I've many software and docs on virtual xp. So is there a way that I can keep both OS or transfer them on workstation?

Comment: Also, Windows 8 works fine on VMWare player

Comment: Uninstall VM Player isn't going to wipe your virtual machines.

Answer (score 3):

The setup will only remove/upgrade VMWare Player, not the actual Virtual Machines.

If you are worried, you can take a backup of your virtual machine folder before starting the installation.

Once the new version is installed, simply look for the `.VMX` files that were in the Virtual Machine folder and your VMs should run fine inside VMware Workstation.